# Toggle Classes with Local Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to toggle an active class for a single button in each row. I can toggle the class on, but I cannot figure out how to remove it once the condition has changed.

### Please see [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/515oQ9QZjYh2o5lOifJY?p=preview).

At this point I have a local `ng-repeat` variable, `active`, that I am using to store the index of the active button.

```
<button ng-repeat="c in laneColors"
        ng-click="laneData[g].base = c; active = $index"
        ng-class="(active===$index) ? 'active' : ''">
```

I hoped the active class would be removed once the condition, `active===$index`, was no longer met, but it only continues to add the class to all buttons clicked.

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/kM8MFo?p=preview

Comment: @PSL yes, exactly. thank you. do you know why it wasn't working before?

Comment: It did not work in your code because the `active` property was set on the each of the child scopes, so you cannot really compare that. If you set it on its parent, then it is shared across all of the children under that parent...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting active based on index, check if the button value is the same of the selected color.

```
<button ng-repeat="c in laneColors"
        ng-click="laneData[g].base = c"
        ng-class="(c===laneData[g].base) ? 'active' : ''">
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EEWo4pY5B8okJMeJ90W0?p=preview)